# How do I reduce the number of variables and connections for php connecting to mysql server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to reduce the number of connections that this page makes.  Everything I read says that only one connection should be enough however if I remove the additional connections the page doesn't connect to my server and provide me the results I am looking for.  Also one of the queries I am using twice but if I call the original query the second time it also does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$dbaddress="localhost";
$dbuser="testuser";
$dbpass="testpass";
$dbname="testdb";
$dbtable="elo";
$query="SELECT Sequnce, mcacctname FROM  `elo`;";
$con=mysqli_connect($dbaddress,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysql_connect($dbaddress, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$sql = "SELECT Sequence, mcacctname FROM  `elo`;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
mysql_connect($dbaddress, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$sql2 = "SELECT Sequence, mcacctname FROM  `elo`;";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$sqlstart = "SELECT mcacctname, elo  FROM  `elo`;";
$q = mysql_query($sqlstart);
?>
<form name="player1" method="post" action="predictions.php">
<label for="Select Player 1">Select Player 1:
<?php
echo "<select name='elouser1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['Sequence'] . "'>" . $row['mcacctname'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Player 1 Wins">
</form>
<br>
<form name="player2" method="post" action="predictions.php">
<label for="Select Player 2">Select Player 2:
<?php
echo "<select name='elouser2'>";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row2['Sequence'] . "'>" . $row2['mcacctname'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Player 2 Wins">
</form>
<table>
<tr>
<?
echo '<div class="container">';
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo '<tr><td><div class="item">'.  $res['mcacctname'] . '</td><td>' . $res    ['elo'] . '</div></td></tr>';
}
echo '</div>';
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could make an (all-exclusive) move over to `MySQLi_` and use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) am just not sure if that function exists for `MySQL_` - plus I noticed you're using both `MySQL_` and `MySQLi_` drop the `MySQL_` and use/pass `$con` to your queries. That way you'll only use one connection (call). I.e.: `$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- `mysql_*()` doesn't support multi-query. `mysqli_*` does, but there are complexities in reading the data which, for three queries, makes it overkill.

Comment: @OP I think you meant `SELECT Sequence` and not `SELECT Sequnce`

Comment: @MikeW That's what I thought. I didn't find it when I Google'd it.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a connection is open in a page you don't need to re-open it for each query. You can simply remove all the statements that create a connection and select the database, except the first one.

**Note** you're using `mysqli` to open the connection, but `mysql` to query it. The two sets of functions are not interchangeable: use `mysqli` as 'mysql' is deprecated and support will be removed in the future.

Try this:

```
$dbaddress="localhost";
$dbuser="testuser";
$dbpass="testpass";
$dbname="testdb";
$dbtable="elo";
$query="SELECT Sequence, mcacctname FROM  `elo`;";
$con=mysqli_connect($dbaddress,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql = "SELECT Sequence, mcacctname FROM  `elo`;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$sql2 = "SELECT Sequence, mcacctname FROM  `elo`;";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$sqlstart = "SELECT mcacctname, elo  FROM  `elo`;";
$q = mysqli_query($con, $sqlstart) or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
<form name="player1" method="post" action="predictions.php">
<label for="Select Player 1">Select Player 1:
<?php
echo "<select name='elouser1'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['Sequence'] . "'>" . $row['mcacctname'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Player 1 Wins">
</form>
<br>
<form name="player2" method="post" action="predictions.php">
<label for="Select Player 2">Select Player 2:
<?php
echo "<select name='elouser2'>";
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row2['Sequence'] . "'>" . $row2['mcacctname'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Player 2 Wins">
</form>
<table>
<tr>
<?
echo '<div class="container">';
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
echo '<tr><td><div class="item">'.  $res['mcacctname'] . '</td><td>' . $res    ['elo'] . '</div></td></tr>';
}
echo '</div>';
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$query="SELECT Sequence, mcacctname FROM  `elo`;";` ;-)

Comment: Actually, the OP made the initial typo.

Comment: OP's typo, but fixed.

Comment: Awesome that solved one of my problems.  I guess I had no idea because I have been pasting the code from various websites sometimes I grab out dated information.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it about a minute ago. Comment added under OP's question.

Comment: @user2869135 What's the other problem(s)?

Comment: It seems like both `$sql` and `$sql2` are using the same query values. One of which could be discarded.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I tried getting rid of the duplicate query however it does not populate my dropdown box when I do this.

Comment: @user2869135 You could discard `$sql2 = "SELECT Sequence, mcacctname FROM  `elo`;";` and use `$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));` then.

Comment: I have revised my code though which seems to solve the problem of the duplicate query.  Maybe because I had to have an additional result variable?

Comment: @user2869135 You can use the same query for multiple use while using a different variable, that works. (as shown in my above example). However there surely is a better way, but I'm not a pro at SQL. I do well for myself, but not a pro.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone I was totally stuck on this one.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I would use the selection made by the user to post that information to the following page?  I read a few sites and from what I gathered I can't do it without javascript or ajax.

Comment: @user2869135 That's really a new question. You don't need AJAX if you post to a whole new page. Read the PHP manual on [form handling](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Thanks again, that lead me to where I needed to go.